# Dolphin on Mint: "/mnt/some_id does not exist" ... but it does

Tags: linux-mint, mount, nemo, dolphin

Linux Mint 21.2, Cinnamon 5.8.4

I saw the entry with [Dolphin on Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300943/the-file-or-folder-media-partitionname-foldername-does-not-exist-kubuntu-dolp), but it wasn't useful in my case.

My PC has three drives: OS, Work, and Backup.

I much prefer Dolphin to Nemo or Nautilus. When I open Dolphin and try to navigate to Work, it tells me /mnt/some_id does not exist.

PCManFM-GTK can see it.

The drive is not listed under /media/Me, but Backup is.

In Drives, Work is shown as mounted, and the mount point shown there is the same one that Dolphin says doesn't exist.

None of this makes any sense to me at all. I'd like all facets of my system to operate consistently.

To sum up: the drive at /mnt/some_id works for some apps, but not all. Some apps say it doesn't exist.

The goal: the drive at /mnt/some_id should exist for all apps

Comment: Without the actual data from the system its difficult to advise. What are the real device names? The actual paths? How did you verify the name you expected represents a device? What does "mount" tell you?

Comment: Real device names: define "real" please. I don't know what that's asking for.

Actual paths: /mnt/765296A752966C1D

Verify: This question doesn't make any sense to me. I'm looking at the device both physically (yep, that's an ssd alright) and reading the file system, Nemo has it listed as  a Device in the treeview as 8TB-20200620 and as /mnt/765... in the address bar.

"Mount": /dev/sdf2 on /mnt/765296A752966C1D type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show)

Comment: The device names refers to a file in /dev/ (sdf2 in your case). But there can also be a layer of indirection provided by symbolic links in /dev/. i.e. you've filled in a lot of the blanks with your comment there. Nemo is using the drive attributes to generate a name - not really relevant to the core issue. I suspect that what you are seeing here relates to how "work" is interpreted in Dolphin - /mnt/765296A752966C1D appears to be a randomly assinged mount point rather than a consistent name. So the puzzle has 2 parts: what (in the context of Dolphin) is "work"

Comment: and why do the other file managers use a consistent name for this.